# How can one jump someone's location in Gather Town?

Tags: gather-town

I sometimes uses [Gather Town](https://gather.town/) for conferences. How can one jump someone's location in Gather Town?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no way to jump, but one can track someone's location as follows: 1) search someone's name 2) click on them 3) follow.

[image]